# Stop watch with Resume functility after page load

Tags: javascript, php, stopwatch, time-tracking

I want to create a stopwatch which has a resume facility like if I have to pause my watch then after page load it will show  my last run time and start from my last time when I resume it (it will be in pause condition) 
**Note:**
It will also in running condition after page load If I did not pause it

I have tried this `[stopwatch][1]` with some reference so I am able to manage running condition if the watch is not paused but I am not finding any suitable solution for when watch is paused and I reload page I will show my last paused time and resume from here if I resume it again...

My HTML Code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vanilla JS Stopwatch - Javascript Stopwatch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    #timerContainer {
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      width:700px;
      margin:20px auto;
      min-height: 60px;
      border-top:0px;
    }
    .timer, .reset {
      float:left;
      width: 54%;
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align:center;
      color: #fff;
      background: #A90000;
      cursor: pointer
    }
    .reset {
      background: #550000;
      color: white;
      width:14.9%;
      border-left: 1px solid #990000;
    }
    .reset:hover {
      background: #CC0000;
    }
    .lighter {
      background: #CC0000
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="timerContainer">
    <div class="timer" onclick="startTimer()">Start Studying!</div>
    <div class="startTimer reset" onclick="startTimer()" >
      <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="pauseTimer reset" onclick="pauseTimer()" >
      <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="resetTimer reset" onclick="resetTimer()">Reset</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="stopWatch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file **stopWatch.js**

```
  var startTimerButton = document.querySelector('.startTimer');
var pauseTimerButton = document.querySelector('.pauseTimer');
var timerDisplay = document.querySelector('.timer');
var start = false;
var pause = false;
var stop = false;



var Clock = {


  totalSeconds: times(),

  start: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
      self.totalSeconds += 1;

       var hours = Math.floor((self.totalSeconds / 3600));
      var minutes = Math.floor((self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60 ));
      var seconds = Math.floor((self.totalSeconds % 60 ));
      hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
      minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      $(".timer").html(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    }, 1000);

  },

  pause: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
  },

  resume: function () {
    if (!this.interval) this.start();
  },
  reset: function () {
    if (!this.interval && !this.start()) {clearInterval(this.interval); this.reseter();}
  },
  reseter: function(){
   var self = this;
    self.totalSeconds = 0;

      $(".timer").html("00:00:00");


    },
    pauseTracker:function() {
        var self = this;
        var tracker_started = check_cookie_name("tracker_started");
var tracker_paused = check_cookie_name("tracker_paused");

start_time_last =  ( tracker_paused - tracker_started ) / 1000; 

    self.totalSeconds = start_time_last;
 $(".timer").html("00:00:00");

    }
};

//

function startTracker(argument) 
{
    if (start == false) 
    {
        Clock.start();
        if (!check_cookie_name("tracker_started")) {

        document.cookie = "tracker_started="+new Date().getTime()+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2020 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

        }
        pause = false;
    }
        start = true;
}
function pauseTimer(argument)
{
    if (pause == false) 
    {
        Clock.pause();
        document.cookie = "tracker_paused="+new Date().getTime()+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2020 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        start = false;
    }
        pause = true;
        stop = false;
}

function resetTimer(argument) 
{
    if (stop == false && start == false && pause == true) 
    {



                document.cookie = "tracker_started="+new Date().getTime()+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
                document.cookie = "achtimerstart="+new Date().getTime()+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
                document.cookie = "achtimerid="+new Date().getTime()+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
                document.cookie = "achtid="+new Date().getTime()+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
                document.cookie = "achpid="+new Date().getTime()+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
                Clock.reset();
                start = false;
                pause = false;
                swal({title: "success", text: "Time has been locked successfully!", type: "success"},
               function(){ 
                   location.reload();
               });
            }



        stop = true;
}


function check_cookie_name(name) 
{
  var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
  if (match) {
    return (match[2]);
  }
  else{
       console.log('--something went wrong---');
  }
}




function startTimer(){

    if (start == false && pause == true) {
            startTracker();
            return false;
        }

    }





function times(){

var tracker_started = check_cookie_name("tracker_started");
if (tracker_started) {
    var current =  new Date().getTime();
    start_time_last =  ( current - tracker_started ) / 1000; 
setTimeout(function(argument) {
          startTracker();
     },500);


    return start_time_last;
}else{
  return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't stored any values anywhere, either on a server or locally in cookies, so how is the browser meant to resume on refresh?

Comment: Please don't link to code off-site. Questions should have all the relevant code in the question itself. Otherwise, this question won't be that helpful for new visitors when that link stops working. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I am using local storage to store the time on page load to continue the watch but I am not able to manage the watch if it is in pause condition and page refresh

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand your consult I have edited my question please have a look at this now

Answer (score 0):

If you want stuff to be persisted across session reloads you need to store the data somewhere. You can try using `localStorage` for that purpose.

Comment: I am using cookies to store the time I have edited my code and place original code ... Please have a look at this